# Are there hardware-embedded operating systems?

Tags: operating-system

I've read in Tanenbaum's Computer architecture that OS's kernel doesn't necessarily have to be stored as executable file, but can be directly implemented in circuit and perform syscalls and other functions by hardware. Are there real examples of such systems (say, Linux or any micro-OS, specially developed for implementing in circuits)?

Comment: It's common that operating systems for small embedded systems are stored in some kind of read-only memory (not FLASH), which also was common for older systems. But actually "hard" coded in the electronics? I doubt that. Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the quote from the book so we can see for ourselves that he is saying.

Comment: OS and other code binary can be directly blown into flash memory and executed directly from a reset vector or bootloader.  That is very common indeed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know the details of the architectures, but you could argue that new technologies such as AWS Nitro, TCP offload to smartNICs, etc., are a step in this direction though, particularly as OS abstractions are now much better understood than in the past and people (especially cloud providers) feel more comfortable hard-coding them into hardware for performance and efficiency.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Recent papers like [The Last CPU](https://sigops.org/s/conferences/hotos/2021/papers/hotos21-s01-nider.pdf) show this trend, too.

Comment: Decentralized architecture like the ones envisioned by that paper have ben put forward at least a few times each computer generation since the invention of the computer. And many of the acceleration techniques used are either fixed-function pipeline (like early GPU's) or software-driven (like almost all modern hardware). Actually burning software-functionality into silicon using transistors is extremely expensive, would use more die-space than it would save, and is impossible to maintain and update on a continuous basis,